# Java generic method, how to make two parameters to have the same type?

Tags: java

I have the following interface and classes:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    ...
}

public class TypeA implements SomeInterface {
    ...
}

public class TypeB implements SomeInterface {
    ...
}
```

And I have the following method in some other class:

```
public static <T extends SomeInterface> void foo(T a, T b) {
    ...
}
```

Now, how do I make sure both `a` and `b` are from the same class? (either both `TypeA` or both `TypeB`, and I want to get compilation error when the first one is `TypeA` but the second one is `TypeB`)

---

One solution I found is to add a type to the interface, like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {
    ...
}

public class TypeA implements SomeInterface<TypeA> {
    ...
}

public class TypeB implements SomeInterface<TypeB> {
    ...
}
```

And also modify the method like this:

```
public static <T> void foo(SomeInterface<T> a, SomeInterface<T> b) {
    ...
}
```

This solutions **works** but it seems a bit weird to me because I have to write the class name twice: `class A implements SomeInterface<A>`. I'm wondering if there are any better solutions than the one above. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with your first solution?

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what the interface and the method do? What should happen if the method receives instances of two different subclasses of `TypeA` as arguments?

Comment: @user2357112 There won't be subclasses of `TypeA`. but I want to get a compilation error when the first parameter is `TypeA` and the second parameter is `TypeB`

Comment: @JBNizet The compiler will upcast `a` and `b` until there is an appropriate superclass that both have in common - for example `Interface`. The doesn't guarantee that `a` and `b` are of the same type, just that they are both assignable to one.

Comment: Can you please avoid **every** calling a `class` `Interface` even in examples - it is extremely bad practice as it is very confusing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I guess you are right.. will make the change

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Nothing in the question seems to call a class `Interface`. The thing referred to as `Interface` is an interface.

Comment: The foo method should probably be an instance method of a generic `class Fooer<T extends Interface>`. Using a `Fooer<TypeA>` would forbid calling it with TypeB, and vice-versa.

Comment: I find this case highly analogous to the standard library `Comparable` interface, which needs to ensure in its `compareTo` method that `this` and the argument are not just `Comparable`, but comparable to each other. It uses pretty much the same solution you've come up with.

Comment: @user2357112 very good point.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use if these are the only two interfaces:

```
public static <T extends SomeInterface> void foo(TypeA a, TypeA b) {
public static <T extends SomeInterface> void foo(TypeB a, TypeB b) {
```

but your solution will also work when there are unknown number of interfaces.